# Question followed by an explanation / clarification etc of the question in the sentence ... how to punctuate?

Tags: punctuation

Is there a standard or preferred way to punctuate this sentence?

> Would you prefer that or the status quo, which is ...

The first half is definitely a question, while the second half is definitely a statement. I'm conflicted as to whether to end the sentence with a question mark or period, or whether to use a question mark mid sentence (which intuitively seems quite odd).

Comment: *Would you prefer that or the status quo?* is a question, and needs a question mark. It does not matter what subordinate clauses follow it - it will **always** be a question and **always** need a question mark, e.g. "*Would you prefer that or the status quo, which is all that I can offer you?*

Answer (score 1):

If you use actual parentheses, the use of the question mark becomes apparent:

> Would you like to eat an apple?
>   Would you like to eat an apple <s>(which is a kind of round fruit)</s>?

The same is true of the nonessential, appositive information provided in the question after the comma:

> Would you prefer that or the status quo?
>   Would you prefer that or the status quo<s>, which is . . .</s>?

---

But as with anything that *looks* strange, even if it's *correct*, it may not be useful to keep it phrased as it's been written.

For instance, the sentence could be rephrased:

> This is *x*. The status quo is *y*. Which would you prefer?
>   Knowing that the status quo is *x*, which would you prefer?

You could use actual or a dash:

> Would you prefer that or the status quo (which is *x*)?
>   Would you prefer that or the status quo—which is *x*?

Or it could be broken into two parts:

> Would you prefer that or the status quo? (The status quo is *x*.)

Last, depending on the nature of the missing information from the question, it could be used adjectivally:

> Would you prefer that or the *x* status quo?